# Database Files and Filegroups

Tags: sql-server, filegroups

In my case wherein I have a file `file_01.mdf` and `file_02.ndf` under 1 filegroup, if ever `file_01.mdf` was already full (no autogrowth enabled), will it give me error on `file_01.mdf` if data is attempted to be added in it?

Comment: Is this something you're having a hard time testing on your own?

Comment: yes. I am just a newbie DBA. What steps should I take to test this?. Also, I am not that familiar specifically in the behavior of files and filegroups.

Comment: I'll answer that with a question: what steps would you want someone else to take to answer your question?

Comment: step by step? instructional? an overview?

Comment: That's exactly how you should write your test! This sounds like a great learning process for a new DBA.

Comment: Comments like this are why I stopped answering questions on forums. Edgar asked a basic question that Dominique proved was able to be answered in a short statement. But instead of providing an answer a bunch of questions where asked that don't give any insight into the answer to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you won't get an error until both datafile are full.. The error is thrown when there is no more space in the filegroup (not for every file in it).

You can test it pretty easily by creating a database with 2 data file (one with the auto-growth enable) and inserting data in it until it fills the first data file.

You will see the the first file fills up to 100% and you won't get any error.
If you disable the auto-growth on the second file and continue inserting, we will get an error when both file will be filled.

Thanks.